# When you recreate your Firebase backend functions and redo the setup, does the project ignore the original set of functions?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase project that uses some Firestore triggers and backend Typescript functions. Let's call the folder for the original set of backend functions `CloudFunctions1`. This was working great. Recently, I completed recreated my cloud functions, going through the whole process of doing `firebase init`, `firebase login`, even adding the extensions I wanted in VSCode. I did this so that my project starts with the latest base skeleton since it had been years since I started the project initially. The new folder for this is called `CloudFunctions2`.

How does my app know to call the functions in `CloudFunctions2` instead of the functions in `CloudFunctions1`? When I did the setup, I selected a project, sure, but does that mean that that project will now completely ignore/disregard the functions in `CloudFunctions1`?

**index.ts:**

```
import {onDocumentCreated} from "firebase-functions/v2/firestore";
import {onDocumentUpdated} from "firebase-functions/v2/firestore";
import {onDocumentDeleted} from "firebase-functions/v2/firestore";
import {onCall} from "firebase-functions/v2/https";
import {HttpsError} from "firebase-functions/v2/https";

exports.callGroupRTDBSetup = onCall({cors: true}, async (req) => {
  try {
    const groupID = req.data.groupID;
    const adminUID = req.data.adminUID;
    const adminUsername = req.data.adminUsername;
    const createdTimestamp = req.data.createdTimestamp;

    await setGroupAdminRTDB(groupID, adminUID, adminUsername, createdTimestamp);

    await addMemberRTDB(groupID, adminUID, adminUsername, createdTimestamp);

    return {
      returnVal: 1,
      returnMsg: "callGroupRTDBSetup success!",
    };
  } catch (error) {
    throw new HttpsError("invalid-argument", "Error: " + error);
  }
});

/**
 * Sets the admin information into the group node in RTDB
 * @param {string} groupID
 * @param {string} adminUID
 * @param {string} adminUsername
 * @param {number} createdAdminTimestamp
 * @return {Promise<{returnVal: number, returnMsg: string}>} A Promise that
 * resolves with an object containing the return value and message.
 */
async function setGroupAdminRTDB(
  groupID: string,
  adminUID: string,
  adminUsername: string,
  createdAdminTimestamp: number
): Promise<{returnVal: number; returnMsg: string}> {
  let returnVal = 0;
  let returnMsg = "";

  const nodeRef = await admin
    .database()
    .ref("app/groups/" + groupID + "/admin/")
    .once("value");

  const data = nodeRef.val();

  if (data == null) {
    try {
      const adminData = {
        adminUsername: adminUsername,
        createdAdminTimestamp: createdAdminTimestamp,
      };

      await admin
        .database()
        .ref("app/groups/" + groupID + "/admin/" + adminUID)
        .set(adminData);

      returnVal = 1;
      returnMsg = "Data successfully added!";
    } catch (error) {
      returnVal = 0;
      returnMsg = "ERROR: " + error;
    }
  } else {
    returnVal = 0;
    returnMsg = "Error: data already exists at admin node";
  }

  return {returnVal: returnVal, returnMsg: returnMsg};
}
```

I deploy these functions using `firebase deploy`.

Comment: What do you mean by "set of backend functions"?  How are you defining a "set" with a name? It would be more clear if you show your code and commands you use the deploy it.

Comment: @DougStevenson added some examples from my `index.ts`. This is the only file I use to define my custom backend code. I put my Firestore triggers in here along with some general functions to insert/update/delete records in Firestore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`firebase deploy` will simply overwrite all previously deployed functions with the new functions by the time it's done executing.  It doesn't matter where your run the command. The old functions are gone and the new ones take their place immediately. The client cannot choose to invoke the old versions.